# Does means the conv2 and conv3 layers are useless?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm training a CNN for binary classification using Tensorflow. Owing to the tensorboard, we can easily check the distribution for each filters. The following is my screenshot:

[image: data distribution]

The `*/summaries/histogram` is from `weights` and the `*/summaries_1/histogram` is from `biases`. My question is: from the `conv2` and `conv3`, it seems the data distribution of weights is constant. Does this means these two layers are useless?

Comment: Not really. It means, the gradient values are vanished. You may choose to change the loss function and learning rate.

Comment: Hi, @IshantMrinal, thanks for comment. The network has 4 conv layers and 1 fully-connected layer. It should not have the vanishing gradient problem. But it seems to have, as you said. I've tried different learning rates. The loss is softmax_with_cross_entropy loss.